# Optimize feature normalization code

Tags: matlab, performance, optimization, octave

Given a matrix `X` with an arbitrary number of columns and rows (Each row representing a feature of the dataset), I want to normalize each value to be `((value - column mean) / column standard deviation)`. I came up with the following code, which works.  Can this be optimized for less computation or is this optimal?

```
mu = mean(X);
sigma = std(X);
x_ones = ones(size(X));
zero_mean_X = X - x_ones * diag(mu);
X_norm = zero_mean_X ./ (x_ones * diag(sigma));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an optimization using `bsxfun` from Matlab

```
M = mean(X);
S = std(X);
Y = bsxfun(@minus,X, M);
Y = bsxfun(@rdivide, Y, S);
```

It is faster by 4 times

[image]

```
X = rand(1000);

t = zeros(100,2);
for ii = 1:100
    tic;
    M = mean(X);
    S = std(X);
    Y = bsxfun(@minus,X, M);
    Y = bsxfun(@rdivide, Y, S);
    t(ii,1) = toc;
end


for ii = 1:100
    tic;
    mu = mean(X);
    sigma = std(X);
    x_ones = ones(size(X));
    zero_mean_X = X - x_ones * diag(mu);
    X_norm = zero_mean_X ./ (x_ones * diag(sigma));
    t(ii,2) = toc;
end

figure('Color', 'w');
plot(t);
legend({'bsxfun', 'matrix'});
xlabel('NUmber of simulations');
ylabel('Time');
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.  The speed testing is a nice bonus.  Good tool to have.

Comment: Wait before accepting the answer - some power users might join the party!

Comment: @marsei there's no better way to do it other than `bsxfun`.  In fact the duplicate I've marked uses this as the best way to do it.